# why all hard drives in a HPC cluster must be of the same size and part number?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hpc

One of the hard drives of my HPCC is broken and I have to buy another one. I've heard it must be of the exactly same size and part number. Could anyone explain me why?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably ask the people that you heard it from.

Comment: @mfinni Right, particularly since saying "HPC cluster" is like saying "mainframe" or "hyperconverged" or even "server".  There's lots of different ones, and not all have the same requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact hardware (HPC cluster can mean a lot of things), it might be that the hardware used require disks with a vendor specific firmware and can't/won't operate with generic disks.

Size wise, you obviously need at least the same size as the replaced disk, which usually ends you up with exactly one available model from your vendor that you need to use (and pay heavily for if out of support).